# How can I used Windows Mobile center in Xp?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-mobile

I used windows xp and I want to used windows mobile center in xp.How can i Used windows mobile center in xp.It's work on Vista and Windows 7 or higher version. I want to use Active Synch. in xp without window mobile center i can't use Active Synch.

Comment: How exactly does your question relate to C#? As of know I'd say this question belongs on SuperUser or some other site...

Comment: Please re-write your question with more clarity

Comment: It's called **Activesync**, not ending with an `h`. JFYI Windows XP is no longer supported by Microsoft (only SP3 until 1st quarter 2012), their recommendation is to move to Windows 7.

Comment: Thank For Replay I found Solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Windows Mobile Center](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14) is only for Windows Vista or Windows 7.

**System requirements**
**Supported Operating Systems:** Windows Vista

- Windows Mobile Device Center 6.1 is currently only available for the following versions of Microsoft Windows Vista™.
- Windows 7 Ultimate
- Windows 7 Enterprise
- Windows 7 Professional
- Windows 7 Home Premium
- Windows 7 Starter
- Windows Vista Ultimate
- Windows Vista Enterprise
- Windows Vista Business
- Windows Vista Home Premium
- Windows Vista Home Basic
- Windows Vista Server

I believe what you are looking for is [ActiveSync](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15), which was what Windows XP used.